# Osmdroid recent repository not able to download

Tags: osmdroid

I am not able to download the 5.6.5 osmdroid library. It take me to [this](https://jar-download.com/explore-java-source-code.php?a=osmdroid-geopackage&g=org.osmdroid&v=5.6.5&downloadable=0) page .Which version should I use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow instructions on osmdroid page https://osmdroid.github.io/osmdroid :

Add this to your gradle file:

```
repositories {
        mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:5.6.4'
}
```

Or if you cannot use gradle you can download it here: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/releases

Comment: Yes. Did that it worked perfectly. I successfully got the world map set to a particular set of geo co-ordinates. Any ideas on How do I get the current user location? Should I put my current code to the question too?